# python,nltk 2.7 is showing error in the code, what could be the solution?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am building an algorithm for sentiment analysis which could segment do the segmentation on a .txt corpus, but there has been some problem in the code I dont know how to resolve?

```
class Splitter(object):
def _init_(self):
    self.nltk_splitter = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english/pickle')
    self.nltk_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer()
def split(self,text):
    """imput format: a .txt file
               output format : a list of lists of words.
               for eg [['this', 'is']['life' , 'worth' , 'living']]"""
    sentences = self.nltk_splitter.tokenize(text)
    tokenized_sentences = [self.nltk_tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return tokenized_sentences
```

and then I did the following things

```
 >>> f = open('amazonshoes.txt')
 >>> raw = f.read()
 >>> text = nltk.Text(raw)
 >>> splitter = Splitter()
 >>> splitted_sentences = splitter.split(text)
```

and the error is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
      splitted_sentences = splitter.split(text)
    File "<pyshell#14>", line 9, in split
      sentences = self.nltk_splitter.tokenize(text)
AttributeError: 'Splitter' object has no attribute 'nltk_splitter'
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of the class `Splitter` should be called `__init__`, with two leading and trailing underscores.

Currently the `_init_` method (single underscore) is not executed, so the `Splitter` object your create (by  calling `Splitter()`) never acquires the attribute/field `nltk_splitter`